# Model fit training number

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Here is my fit method

```
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)



 Fit model on training data
Epoch 1/2
782/782 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5879 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8403 - val_loss: 0.1954 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9453
Epoch 2/2
782/782 [==============================] - 1s 824us/step - loss: 0.1732 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9496 - val_loss: 0.1287 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9618
```

Here what is 782? you can see after epoch 2/2 there is 782/782. i would like to know what is the number(782)

Answer (score 1):

782 is the total number of batches processed in each epoch. As your model trains you can see batch counter growing from 0 to 782.
Apparently your dataset size is about 50000. When you divide 50K by 64 (batch size) you get just under 782. This means that the last batch's size will be smaller than 64.

Comment: but you can see that I have set batch_size = 64 in the fit method. so what does that mean?

Comment: You specify the batch size(64 datapoints) and `fit()` splits your dataset into the needed number of batches (782).
`781 * 64 + 1 * 16 = 50000`

Comment: more info about `tf.keras.fit()` is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)